# How to save ActiveForm to database? Why I get "Integrity constraint violation"?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have this test app written in Yii 2.0. One model, one form. 
When I click save button I got error:

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: test.col1
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `test` DEFAULT VALUES

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 19
    [2] => NOT NULL constraint failed: test.col1
)

↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: test.col1

in /home/bps/workspace/test/YiiTest/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 963
```

at line with $model->save(). Why my form is unable to save my data to database?

**sql**

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, col2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

**file db.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlite:@app/sqlite3.db',
];
```

**file Test.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Test extends ActiveRecord {
    public $col1;
    public $col2;

    public static function tableName(){
        return 'test';
    }

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['col1', 'col2'], 'required']
        ];
    }
}
```

**file test.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'test';
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'col1')->textInput(); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'col2')->textArea(); ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton(); ?>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div>record count: <?= $num_records ?></div>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <li><?= $item->col1 ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionTest(){
        $model = new Test();

        // add items
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost){
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
                $model->save();
            }
        }

        // schow items
        $items = Test::find();
        return $this->render('test', [
            'num_records' => $items->count(),
            'items' => $items->all(),
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you defined attributes:

```
class Test extends ActiveRecord {
    public $col1;       // here
    public $col2;       // and here
```

If you want to work this properly, remove this, ActiveRecord is automatically mapping columns from your table.